# React/React-Native most performant way of subscribing to onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, charts, onchange

I'm doing a react native project while using a wrapper for MPAndroidChart (react-native-charts-wrapper), but I think this question extends beyond my use case.

Within a component which renders two charts, I use the charts onChange prop to set the position of the second chart, and vice versa, as they show data over the same time scale (see gif). Here is the method:

```
syncToChart2(event) {
    if (
        event.action === 'chartScaled' ||
        event.action === 'chartTranslated'
    ) {
        let { scaleX, scaleY, centerX, centerY } = event;
        this.chart2Zoom = {
            scaleX: scaleX,
            scaleY: scaleY,
            xValue: centerX,
            yValue: centerY
        };
    }
}
```

Currently, the graphs sync too slowly to transformations as can be seen here:
[slow transformation sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2Ox.gif)

I was previously using setState to subscribe to the changes, but that was slower than using the MobX observable decorator, the effect of which can be seen in the gif. I am looking to improve the code still.

So the question is, what is the most performant way to subscribe to a change that happens very often and which needs to reflect instantly?

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is to [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle) these kind of events (scrolling et.c.)